# Can I transfer Ultiboard files to other PCB layout software packages via DXF export/import?

Tags: pcb, software, layout, ultiboard, dxf

I have an extensive library of PCB layouts in Ultiboard format. If, hypothetically, I wanted to switch to another software package, this would pose a problem, as the Ultiboard layout format appears to be proprietary and not documented. (Could be wrong about that.) Ultiboard supports export to:

- Scalable Vector Graphics
- Gerber
- IPC-D-356A Netlist
- 3D IGES
- DXF
- NC Drill

I'm thinking DXF is the most likely format to be supported by other software packages. What other layout packages, if any, support DXF import?

Related questions:
[Importing Drawings ( DXF ) in Altium](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/72779/importing-drawings-dxf-in-altium)
[Gerber to DXF converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/45081/gerber-to-dxf-converter)

Comment: Your best option would likely to be to export from Multisim / Ultiboard, rather than try to import the proprietary format into other tools. Not sure what the best format option is though.

Comment: @Polynomial Agreed, reworded question to fit.

Comment: What do you want to be able to do with the design after importing it into another tool? Just tweak the polygons or actually modify the design?

Comment: @JoeHass I'd be interested to know what the limits are for any given software package.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to make Ultiboard export an uncompressed XML .ewprj file by activating its 'Internal options'. Then you can write your own converter e.g. to Eagle or some other non-proprietary format, but the XML is quite complex and the thing needs some time.
To activate these internal options a binary patch to a DLL is required; once the existence of this option is known, one can find it in a few minutes with a good disassembler. But this is reverse-engineering (NOT cracking!!) stuff and I can't post more details. Maybe I will write the converter myself some day.
Fabio

Answer (score 1):

Gerber and NC Drill are files for manufacturing PCBs - for routing and holes respectively, likewise with the netlist files which define the connections between your components.  IIRC the paid for version of GC-Prevue allows you to edit the gerber data, and as these formats are very standard, you should be able to import into most PCB layout packages.

Generally when you export a schematic to the layout package, it is the netlist which gets sent - but that would then require you to do your layout again.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning what EDA software will allow a Gerber to be imported versus just an external editor. Not that I do a lot of PCB layout but I'm not aware of any that can create library parts from Gerbers.

Comment: While I have not done so myself, I believe that you can import gerbers into native software, like PADS or Altium, but since most part libraries are proprietary to their respective tools, I can't see how you could reverse engineer the parts from the gerber data.  The netlist would have a list of the components, which could be used to generate the required parts.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question as to which software will accept DXF imports, you will have to choose a software, check to see if it will accept DXF imports, if it does then proceed with what ever you wanted to do.

A few that may support this:

1. [Eagle](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/)
    -Eagle only supports direct import of ACCEL-ASCII (aka PCAD ASCII) which can be exported from Altium, Protel, and PCAD. You can import others using a third party company like [LogicSwap](http://www.logicswap.com/). Eagle actually as a page of [tools and converters](http://www.cadsoftusa.com/downloads/tools-and-converters?language=en).
2. [AutoCAD](http://www.artwork.com/tanner/dxf/exp5.htm) I believe it's possible. It was difficult finding
   information on such a popular software. They are the company that created DXF files. So that part is easy.
3. [Design Spark](http://www.designspark.com/) returned my email stating they can import Eagle using eip and eis files.
4. [DipTrace](http://www.diptrace.com/) returned my email stating they can import the following PCB files: PCAD ASCII, Eagle (using our ULP that coverts Eagle board to DipTrace ASCII), PADS ASCII 2005, OrCAD Min Interchange. Moreover, DipTrace can import **Gerber, NC drill and DXF files**.

It seems that DXF is a safe bet. However, they all are different. You'll really have to choose a program then assess what are your best options.

[Gerber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format) file format is a leading format for PCB Design. It is exported by every software. Importing is a different story. It would seem that using a third party company is also a viable option.

Comment: I think you missed the point. The OP is well aware that Ultiboard will export DXF. The OP wanted to know what other layout packages will _import_ DXF, so your answer doesn't really address the question.

Comment: It does too. I listed four of them. After reading the question I do see that the first two lines of my answer are redundant. The rest of the answer is on topic. I edited accordingly.

Comment: Can you clarify whether the software you list is _PCB layout software_ and not general CAD? The OP was interested specifically in porting PCB layouts to another layout tool.